# PHP vs Dart Aes 128 encryption

Tags: php, flutter, dart, encryption, openssl

I am trying to encrypt data in an app (flutter) where I want a server (PHP) to decrypt.

I can't get these both talking to each other.

I've tested it and I get different answers encrypting in PHP vs encrypting in dart. In openSLL in PHP:

```
$ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";
$options = 0;
$decryption_iv = '1234567891011121';
$decryption_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$encryption=openssl_encrypt ("1234", $ciphering, $encryption_key, 
$options,$decryption_iv);
dump($encryption);
```

The encryption is: xpL7dg==

This struck me as odd as I thought I'd get a longer string, perhaps length 16? Or multiple odd? Think $options = 0 is by default including padding.

In flutter:

```
final mykey = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"; //hardcode
final myiv = "1234567891011121"; //hardcode
final keyUtf8 = utf8.encode(mykey);
final ivUtf8 = utf8.encode(myiv);
final key = sha256.convert(keyUtf8).toString().substring(0, 16);
final iv = sha256.convert(ivUtf8).toString().substring(0, 16);
final _iv = IV.fromUtf8(iv);
final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(Key.fromUtf8(key), mode: AESMode.cbc));
final encryptedPass = encrypter.encrypt("1234", iv: _iv);
```

Encryption is hTZYOl0M9CgZ3lns2eU9WQ== base64

So I guess - why does PHP give such a short encrypted output? What am I doing such that these aren't matching?

Comment: It is quite obvious that both codes use different operation modes (CTR vs CBC). In addition, unlike the PHP code, the Dart code uses SHA256 for key and IV derivation.

Comment: Regarding *...why does PHP give such a short encrypted output?...*: CTR is a stream cipher mode. Stream cipher modes do not require padding (and PHP/OpenSSL automatically disables padding for stream cipher modes).

Comment: Thank you, that is useful and I have now got it working and matching on both sides with an encryption key of length 16. PHP openSSL still works if the key length is 15, do you know what it does to 'lengthen' this?

Comment: PHP/OpenSSL extends keys that are too short by silently padding the key to the required length (16 bytes for AES-128) with 0x00 values (keys that are too long are simply truncated).